# AngularJS promise not setting "this" properly

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm attempting to pre-populate a select list with data from a JSON file.

*Controller*

```
this.langs = [];
var promise = $lcidFactory.getLCIDS();
promise.then(
    function(payload){
        this.langs = payload.data;
        console.log(payload.data);
    },
    function(error){
        alert("[Error] "+error);
    }
);
```

When I review the console with the inspector the data appears. However, the following code produces an empty JSON, `{}`.

*HTML*

```
<template-editor-form model="cpCtrl.data">
    ...
    <pre>{{ cpCtrl.langs | json }}</pre>
    ...
</template-editor-form>
```

If I set `this.langs = []` in line 1 of the controller to `this.langs = ["one"]` the template reflects the changes properly, as `["langs": ["one"]]`

*EDIT*
This question is similar to [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), however this question addresses one of the common pitfalls of the usage of `this` in the *context of AngularJS*, in a concise fashion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i guess your problem is that "this" in your function is not the same "this" outside the function. You could set the "outside this" to a variable, so you can use that variable to access your langs even in the callback function.

```
var self = this;
this.langs = [];
var promise = $lcidFactory.getLCIDS();
promise.then(
    function(payload){
        self.langs = payload.data;
        console.log(payload.data);
    },
    function(error){
        alert("[Error] "+error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Silly mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be binding the context to the function which propvides bounded function.

```
this.langs = [];
var promise = $lcidFactory.getLCIDS();
promise.then(
    function(payload){
        this.langs = payload.data;
        console.log(payload.data);
    }.bind(this), 
    function(error){
        alert("[Error] "+error);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is `window` in loose mode or `undefined` in strict mode within callback functions. This can be fixed by

**using ES5 `bind`** ([`angular.bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) may be used instead for legacy browsers)

```
promise.then(
    function(payload){
        this.langs = payload.data;
    }.bind(this),
    ...
```

**using ES6 arrow function**

```
promise.then(
    (payload) => {
        this.langs = payload.data;
    },
    ...
```

**assigning `this` to another variable in parent function scope**

```
var _this = this;

promise.then(
    function(payload){
        _this.langs = payload.data;
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the outer `this` in a variable like `var that = this`, and inside of resolve handler use `that.langs = payload.data`.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in javascript is a bit odd (or different from other language) and scope related, i suggest 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

for your code:

```
this.langs = [];

var base = this;

var promise = $lcidFactory.getLCIDS();
promise.then(
    function(payload){
        base.langs = payload.data;
        console.log(payload.data);
    },
    function(error){
        alert("[Error] "+error);
    }
);
```